# Selecting oracle column header

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I've been browsing and to no avail, I can't find any information on how to select/show only the column header. My objective is to select only column header . I've uploaded a picture for better illustration on my objective. In the picture shown, I'm trying to only select and display the one ive highlighted in the red box.

Oracle table:

[image: screenshot of a table]

The only information I found from the net is selecting an individual column, and with that. It will display the data as well which is not my objective. my main objective is to only select column headings.

Comment: Which tool is it? What will you do once you manage to "select column header"? Are you interested in column list (USERNAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS, ...) without data, or what? Would querying USER_TAB_COLUMNS do any good?

Comment: So, you want to get the same result, but with the actual data excluded? What does your current query look like?

Comment: Yes. I just want to list the column header and nothing more.  Because when my table is empty. When i select * from table name. It shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle APEX SQL Workshop you can describe a table with this command:

```
desc table_name
```

If you're using a query, you can click on the "Describe" tab below the query and above the result grid.

Comment: Thanks , not only it shows the headings but it also list out the data types. :)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar requirement, so in page designer I plugged in a "Where Clause = Sysdate-1"
[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can  use select and null to pick columns and use alias to name them

`select null AS column_name,null AS column_name

 from TABLE_NAME`